# Trying to get property of non-object when trying to echo the attribute of element

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

i keep getting error Trying to get property of non-object on the line
 `$title->$my_xpath->query` when running the script. i have the node and path correct but till not working

```
    $nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//div[@class="info_coupon"]' );       
    foreach( $nodes as $node )
    {
        $title  = $my_xpath->query( 'a', $node )->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo $title;
        $code = $my_xpath->query( 'a/@data-code', $node );
        if( $code->length>0 ) {
        $coupon = $code->item(0)->nodeValue ;
        echo $coupon;        
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think the `<a>` is generated / manipulated thru JS, check out the raw `$html` you got, there's no `<a>` in there

Comment: how do i chk tht? the raw html...whn i do echo $html...the div_coupon with the a is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some javascript manipulation on that page that does the generation of `<a>`. But in essence (when you got the initial `$html`), there is none.

Here's a snippet of what you're getting from the initial lines of your code:

```
$url = "http://zoutons.com/stores/paytm-coupons/";    
$html = file_get_contents($url); <-- this one contains
```

This one:

```
<div class="info_coupon"> 
    <span rel="nofollow" data-lnu="aHR0cDovL3RyYWNraW5nLnZjb21taXNzaW9uLmNvbS9hZmZfYz9vZmZlcl9pZD0xMDIyJmFmZl9pZD0yMDYwJnVybD1odHRwcyUzQSUyRiUyRnBheXRtLmNvbSUyRiUzRnV0bV90ZXJtJTNEe2FmZmlsaWF0ZV9pZH0=" href="http://zoutons.com/stores/paytm-coupons/?#cid=31215" class="heading affiliate affiliate_map c_data_31215" data-affiliate="aHR0cDovL3RyYWNraW5nLnZjb21taXNzaW9uLmNvbS9hZmZfYz9vZmZlcl9pZD0xMDIyJmFmZl9pZD0yMDYwJnVybD1odHRwcyUzQSUyRiUyRnBheXRtLmNvbSUyRiUzRnV0bV90ZXJtJTNEe2FmZmlsaWF0ZV9pZH0="  data-id="31215" data-code="NEW50" data-link_type="text" store="Paytm">GET FREE Rs.50/- ON RECHARGE  (VALID TILL &#8211; APRIL 27)
    </span>
```

So there is really no `<a>` after all.

But the data you're after is actually inside that `<span>`:

```
href="http://zoutons.com/stores/paytm-coupons/?#cid=31215"
data-code="NEW50"
```

So just get it there:

```
$nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//div[@class="info_coupon"]' );       
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    $title = $my_xpath->evaluate('string(./span/@href)', $node);
    $code = $my_xpath->evaluate('string(./span/@data-code)', $node);
    echo $title;
    echo $code;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work for $url="http://www.ciim.in/top-pr-dofollow-social-bookmarking-sites-list-2016";  $nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//table[@class="social_list"]/tbody/tr' ); $title  = $my_xpath->evaluate( 'td[1]/a"]', $node ); ...the result is blank